# Failed to connect to bus

Tags: bash

I tried with restart "sudo shutdown -r 0", but I got an error:
"Failed to connect to bus:no such file or directory"

What does this mean? 
I worked on headless Raspberry on some server configuration and I'm not sure what is wrong. I suspect "Anything Sync Daemon" where I add and remove some folder. But now daemon is stopped, so this shouldn't be a problem. 
Any idea?

Comment: This seems not to be specific for raspberry pi. What says google?

Comment: It seems a general `systemd` problem. Some have reported that `sudo su -` followed by the shutdown or actually logging in as root solves the problem, but others have resorted to removing the power.

Comment: I searched but didn't find a similar problem. I tried many different things, but nothing helps. Full restore will follow.

Answer (score 1):

I saw something similar while resetting the password.  In that case I was in single user mode.  From there, closing the window (Control-D) caused the system to shut down.

Comment: What is "single user mode"?

Comment: As described in this article: http://mapledyne.com/ideas/2015/8/4/reset-lost-admin-password-for-raspberry-pi  you can configure Rasbian to boot into a single user mode.  In that mode you will not be able to use shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian comes with the **systemd init system** since version Jessie. I assume your system has this also running. **systemd** heavily uses **dbus** for interprocess communication and it seems that it is missing. Try to install it and reboot:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install dbus
```